# ajax put request not accepting id in params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a click event triggering an update to a record within a rails app. The server error was that meeting doesn't recognize a string, so I turned the id into an int. Then I ran into a road block. I tried 2 different ways, both server errors are below

```
$('.cancelMeeting').click(function(e)    {
 e.preventDefault();

 console.log(this.href);
 var fullUrl = this.href;
 var hrefLength = (this.href).length;
 var idString = fullUrl.substring(hrefLength-2);
 var id = parseInt(idString);
 console.log(typeof id);
 var source = $(".cancelMeetingPrompt").html();
 var compiled = Handlebars.compile(source);
 $('.meetingHolder').append(compiled());

 $('.confirmCancelMeeting').click(function(e)    {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cancelNotes = $('.cancelNotes').val();
    $.get('/set_user', function(result) {
            var userId = result.id
            console.log(userId);
            console.log(id);

            $.ajax  ({
                type: "PUT",
                url: '/meetings/'+id,
                data: {
                    meeting: id,   **only in second error log below**
                    cancel_user_id: userId,
                    status: 'Cancelled',
                    notes: cancelNotes
                },
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(result)   {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    console.log(typeof id);
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
     })
});



});
```

When I console log typeof id, it says number. But when I run it, the error below is given.

```
Started PUT "/meetings/76" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-06 19:38:00 -0400
Processing by MeetingsController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"cancel_user_id"=>"1", "status"=>"Cancelled", "notes"=>"khkj", "id"=>"76"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Meeting Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "meetings".* FROM "meetings" WHERE "meetings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 76]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: meeting):
  app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:95:in `meeting_params'
  app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:61:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:60:in `update'
```

In the ajax call I pasted above, it does declare meeting :id, to try and remedy that, and it receives this error

```
Started PUT "/meetings/76" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-06 19:41:24 -0400
Processing by MeetingsController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"meeting"=>"76", "cancel_user_id"=>"1", "status"=>"Cancelled", "notes"=>"kjl", "id"=>"76"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Meeting Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "meetings".* FROM "meetings" WHERE "meetings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 76]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "76":String):
  app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:95:in `meeting_params'
  app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:61:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:60:in `update'
```

Why does this not work? Especially considering I'm using the url to send it straight to the controller, so shouldn't it just pull the id passed with the url?

Any clues as to why this isn't working is appreciated. Thanks!

*******UPDATE*******

Thanks to the answer below, I was able to correctly pass the params, but another error arose.

```
Started PUT "/meetings/84" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-06 21:32:46 -0400
Processing by MeetingsController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"meeting"=>{"cancel_user_id"=>"1", "status"=>"Cancelled", "notes"=>"gsdf"}, "id"=>"84"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Meeting Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "meetings".* FROM "meetings" WHERE "meetings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 84]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "meetings" SET "notes" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "meetings"."id" = ?  [["notes", "gsdf"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-07 01:32:46.982349"], ["id", 84]]
   (1.5ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/profile/home
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)


Started PUT "/profile/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-06 21:32:46 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/profile/home"):
```

In the update method rails scaffolding automatically creates, it has a line that was redirecting after update

```
    format.html { redirect_to home_url, notice: 'Your lex is set! Click Plan Meeting to plan some conversation topics.' }
```

Hopefully it helps someone else :)

Comment: Could you add your controller code as well? Particularly the permit method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your error is caused by rails `strong params` in your controller, as indicated by this line: `app/controllers/meetings_controller.rb:95:in 'meeting_params'`.

`(param is missing or the value is empty: meeting)` is indicating that your `meeting_params` method is missing a required key. So, if your `meeting_params` looks something like:

```
def meeting_params
  params.require(:meeting).permit(....)
end
```

Rails is looking for the the required `meeting` key.  In your first example, the params passed in were:

```
{"cancel_user_id"=>"1", "status"=>"Cancelled", "notes"=>"khkj", "id"=>"76"}
```

Rails was expecting a params hash like this:

```
{"meeting" => {"cancel_user_id"=>"1", "status"=>"Cancelled", "notes"=>"khkj", "id"=>"76"}}
```

Modifying your `ajax` request should take care of it:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '/meetings/'+id,
        data: { 
          meeting: {
            id: id,
            cancel_user_id: userId,
            status: 'Cancelled',
            notes: cancelNotes
          }
        },...
```

**Second Error**

When you actually pass `meeting` in the hash your `params` come thorough as:

```
Parameters: {"meeting"=>"76", "cancel_user_id"=>"1", "status"=>"Cancelled", "notes"=>"kjl", "id"=>"76"}
```

Rails actually sees the `meeting` key, because now it is present and calls `permit` on it.  However, `params[:meeting]` returns the string `"76"`. Rails expects to call `permit` on a `hash`. Thus, thats why your seeing the second error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "76":String)
```